# Картинки на слайдере

Tags: css3, slider

Делаю слайдер на сайт, и нужно 11 картинок. 
4 из них идут по порядку, нормально переключаясь, а если нажимаю на следующий (5 слайд), там пусто.
Обнаружил, что картинки склеиваются вдоль по 4, а с 5 по 8 склеиваются под первыми 4.
Вот так: http://s019.radikal.ru/i621/1410/92/ddc567ce054c.jpg
Как сделать так, чтобы все картинки шли одна за другой вдоль?

Comment: Я не забыл правило "каждый уважающий себя программист должен сделать свой JS slider", но всё-таки посоветую: http://www.slidesjs.com/ или https://github.com/gilbitron/Ideal-Image-Slider

Answer (score 1):

Ширина контейнера, вмещающего в себя слайды, должна быть равной сумме ширин всех слайдов. Нужно скриптом посчитать и назначить явно. Без этого по умолчанию ширина контейнера будет не более ширины его родителя.